# Spring TransactionRequiredException exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, transactions, spring-data-jpa

Here is my Repository configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfing {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.imdb.model");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/imdb");
        ds.setUsername("***");
        ds.setPassword("***");
        ds.setInitialSize(5);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

When I call `merge` method, I get an exception: `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call`

May be my `RepositoryConfig` is lacking of some additional configurations?

EDIT:
My new Repository configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepositoryConfing {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.imdb.model");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/imdb");
        ds.setUsername("***");
        ds.setPassword("***");
        ds.setInitialSize(5);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
}
```

Now it fails with `StackOverflow`. May be `DataSourceTransactionManager` is not suit for JPA?

Comment: Can you show me your class doing the `merge` call ? Are your services/repositories spring beans ? Component scanned ?

Comment: @AlexandreJacob Check edits please. Everything work well until I call `merge`/`persist`.

Comment: Check my answer, i'll update accordingly but the *thing* is that you need a `JpaTransactionManager` with a bean ID of `transactionManager`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

- Your `txManager` method should be renamed to `transactionManager`.
- You need to have a `JpaTransactionManager` instead of a `DataSourceTransactionManager`

**EDIT**

In order to have fully functional transaction with JPA you need to :

- Use `@EnableTransactionManagement` on your configuration file
- Declare an `EntityManagerFactoryBean`
- Declare a `JpaTransactionManager` (the bean must be named `transactionManager`) created with your previously declared `EntityManagerFactoryBean`
- Inject (with `@PersistenceContext` or `@Autowired`) an `EntityManager` in your `@Repository` (which must be a spring bean)
- Call your repository from a `@Service` and use a **public** method anotated with `@Transactional`

Of course this is simplified and I assume you are using java config, annotations, and autocomponent scanning.

Comment: oops, actually my problem still exist =(

Comment: I tried to give you a few more pointers in my edited answer, can't help you much with the provided information.

Comment: the cause of stackoverflow is in my repository
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727871/jpa-stackoverflow-on-cascade-merge

Comment: I had an issue where transaction advice (proxying) was not working. All items in the above checklist was checked and fine, still not working.  I narrowed it down that it would work in Spring 4 but not in Spring 3. Eventually found that in Spring 3 you have to use the Spring version of @Transactional rather than the javax.transaction one.